# Cant get Github to show under control version on intellj

Tags: java, android, git, github, intellij-idea

I cant get GitHub to show under control version on IntelliJ

I'm new to GitHub, but I made an account and tried signing in under file->Control Version->GitHub on IntelliJ but it's not showing up.

Screenshot of my screen
[image: https://ibb.co/d0GSVL]

This is what i want to do @ :47
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0s7YYjQEsfU&t=55s

Comment: Tried this one already? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manage-projects-hosted-on-github.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub support is merged with Git support. So if you need to checkout project from GitHub just select "Git" option. Then click on "Login to GitHub". After it you could use URL dropdown to see your GitHub projects.

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings first:

- Settings/Preferences dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>),
- select Version Control | GitHub in the left pane.

Make sure you have your GitHub account registered there.

If not, `File > Settings > Plugins` : install the GitHub integration.

Then try and select GitHub in "Version Control".

Comment: Yes i have the GitHub integration but still doesn't show up

Comment: @L.Flores Even after restarting the IDE?